# Compiling error when overwriting "new"

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm trying to control mem leaks in my code. In my general header file I've added this code:

```
    // You may need to locate mem leaks
    #define ZEL_CHECK_MEMORY_LEAKS
    #ifdef ZEL_CHECK_MEMORY_LEAKS
        #define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
        #include <cstdlib>
        #include <crtdbg.h>

        #ifdef _DEBUG
        #ifndef DBG_NEW
        #define DBG_NEW new ( _NORMAL_BLOCK , __FILE__ , __LINE__ )
        #define new DBG_NEW
        #endif
        #endif  // _DEBUG

        #define zelInitMemoryCheck() \
            _CrtSetDbgFlag( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF)
    #else
        #define zelInitMemoryCheck()
    #endif //ZEL_CHECK_MEMORY_LEAKS
```

If I add this code, I get this compilation error:

```
1>c:\archivos de programa\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xlocmon(283) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_DebugHeapTag_func'
1>        c:\archivos de programa\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xlocmon(281) : while compiling class template member function 'size_t std::moneypunct<_Elem,_Intl>::_Getcat(const std::locale::facet **,const std::locale *)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Intl=true
1>        ]
1>        c:\archivos de programa\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xlocmon(908) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::moneypunct<_Elem,_Intl>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Intl=true
1>        ]
```

In addition, In my source code I have this inclusion:

```
#include "core/zelCoreLib.h"
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

Where mem leak control code is into zelCoreLib.h

To those not have VC9.0 this is the code that "fails"

```
static size_t __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL _Getcat(const locale::facet **_Ppf = 0,
        const locale *_Ploc = 0)
        {   // return locale category mask and construct standard facet
        if (_Ppf != 0 && *_Ppf == 0)
            *_Ppf = _NEW_CRT moneypunct<_Elem, _Intl>(
                _Locinfo(_Ploc->name()), 0, true);
        return (_X_MONETARY);
        }
```

It seems to be part of string and locale facilities. Also, as an additional information, I use Lua and LuaBind libs

Any help will be welcome

Comment: Why don't you use an existing tool like [vld](http://sites.google.com/site/dmoulding/vld)?

Comment: There is absolutely not enough here to go on. Make a _complete_, minimal testcase.

Comment: I've done some minimal examples and all was fine. And is only at this point that I have this error. I could insert all my Log library but I might be excesive.

Comment: `#define new` usually breaks any placement new used by the code or library, so it is generally a bad idea. Not that this seems to be the problem here though.

Comment: It could help if you showed the lines around 280 in xlocmon. Not everyone has VC9 available.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y Seems pretty useful. I'll give a try. But I don't want to loss the oportunity to learn, so I want to solve this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `#define new`.  `new` is a keyword, and `#define`ing it results in undefined behavior if you include any header in the standard library.  The standard library almost certainly uses placement new in some places, for example, and your macro will cause any use of placement new to break.  It will also cause any class specific `new` to break—and the library might use these as well.  You cannot redefine keywords and expect anything to work.

Comment: Yes, I was suspecting something when seeing _NEW_CRT macro in the _Getcat code. It is there a simple solution to this problem? Thanks

Comment: That depends on your definition of simple:-).  Under Linux, just use valgrind, if your code can accept it.  (Code runs about an order of magnitude slower under valgrind, which may mean that it cannot run at all, if e.g. it cannot serve a socket fast enough.)  Otherwise, I've written code which walks the stack back manually, saving the return addresses (which is can output in hex later); it's clearly not portable, however, and generally speaking, I wouldn't call it simple.

Comment: @Killrazor - Microsoft used to do this (DEBUG_NEW) in their older releases, so it is (or was) kind of an implementation specific extension. Here it obviously conflicts with another macro also defining `new`. And, like James says, in other parts of the library it will create conflicts with the use of placement new.

Comment: @Bo Persson Note that nothing prevents him from using `DBG_NEW` rather than `new` in his own code (as long as he ensures that it is also defined in release mode).

Comment: And what if I implement my own definitions of new and delete, for example #define zelNew(block) new(block, _FILE_, _LINE_). I'll need to subtitute all my new calls but, it could be worth?

Comment: @James - Right, he could. The problem is of course this part of the macro sequence `#define new DBG_NEW`, which forces the definition upon everyone. That's what MS used to do once upon a time, before there was a Standard Library using placement new.

Comment: @Killrazor No problem. And it could be worth it, in certain cases.  It's certainly a possibility for a new project (where you don't yet have an code using `new`), and it's probably feasible to globally search and replace all occurrences of `new` as a separate word with `zelNew` in your sources.

Comment: The redefining is part of standard ActiveX. An activeX control has `#ifdef _DEBUG  #define new DEBUG_NEW` defined by default. Of course it is causing conflicts when I try to include `Ogre::Root r = new Ogre::Root();`. Commenting out the #define made things work ok. Is this type of #define outdated? Then why is it still in VS2010?

Comment: @Nav Because VS2010 is broken?  Except that I don't see it in VS2010; I didn't see it in VS2005 either.  Redefining a key word results in undefined behavior, and all sorts of practical problems.  You just don't want to do it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: In my code, we're having this problem in only one project.  Therefore, it's conditionally defined. Presumably upgrades keep it (for backwards compatability) but new projects don't.