# Using DEBUG_NEW with D3DXMATRIXA16

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, operator-overloading, directx

I'm currently implementing leak detection as described here: [Finding Memory Leaks Using the CRT Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Using the following macro, I redefine the new keyword with DEBUG_NEW like described in the article:

```
#ifndef DBG_NEW      
    #define DBG_NEW new ( _NORMAL_BLOCK , __FILE__ , __LINE__ )
    #define new DBG_NEW   
#endif
```

Now I'm using a lot of DirectX code in the project and a call to `new` doesn't compile currently. And that occurs when creating an array of [`D3DXMATRIXA16`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb172913(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
m_pBoneMatrices = new D3DXMATRIXA16[m_maxBones];
```

This is the compiler error that is thrown:

> error C2660: '_D3DXMATRIXA16::operator new[]' : function does not take 4 arguments

I went to the definition of `_D3DXMATRIXA16` and found this in `d3dx9math.h`:

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1300  // VC7
#define D3DX_ALIGN16 __declspec(align(16))
#else
#define D3DX_ALIGN16  // Earlier compiler may not understand this, do nothing.
#endif

typedef struct _D3DXMATRIXA16 : public D3DXMATRIX
{
    _D3DXMATRIXA16() {}
    _D3DXMATRIXA16( CONST FLOAT * );
    _D3DXMATRIXA16( CONST D3DMATRIX& );
    _D3DXMATRIXA16( CONST D3DXFLOAT16 * );
    _D3DXMATRIXA16( FLOAT _11, FLOAT _12, FLOAT _13, FLOAT _14,
                    FLOAT _21, FLOAT _22, FLOAT _23, FLOAT _24,
                    FLOAT _31, FLOAT _32, FLOAT _33, FLOAT _34,
                    FLOAT _41, FLOAT _42, FLOAT _43, FLOAT _44 );

    // new operators
    void* operator new   ( size_t );
    void* operator new[] ( size_t );

    // delete operators
    void operator delete   ( void* );   // These are NOT virtual; Do not 
    void operator delete[] ( void* );   // cast to D3DXMATRIX and delete.

    // assignment operators
    _D3DXMATRIXA16& operator = ( CONST D3DXMATRIX& );

} _D3DXMATRIXA16;

typedef D3DX_ALIGN16 _D3DXMATRIXA16 D3DXMATRIXA16, *LPD3DXMATRIXA16;
```

The compiler is VS2013 so D3DX_ALIGN16 is defined as `__declspec(align(16))`

Now removing the definition of `new` would obviously fix this but **what's the point in doing that if I suspect a memory leak around this code**?

I'm unsure what happens here. Is there any way to circumvent this problem? I still want to be able to debug the allocation here.

Comment: the __declspec(align(16)) shouldn't be the problem. That's normal for aligned DirectX vector types. Are you in debug mode? Are you wrapping it in the #ifdef _DEBUG like in the example? I think this only works in debug mode (with _DEBUG defined), otherwise it won't understand. If that fails, here's a hail mary: actually write DEBUG_NEW. Also beware of issues discussed in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909062/compiling-error-when-overwriting-new

Comment: @mock_blatt `new` is being defined into `DEBUG_NEW` at the end of my includes section, there are not any includes below it. Also it's not an issue to not define it in release build, both Debug & Release builds can't compile this code. Though I just found out that D3DXMATRIXA16 overloads the `new` and `delete` operators (see my edit).
So it's kind of impossible to do something here, right?

Comment: @Vinzenz usage of such defines (like DBG_NEW) requires that class\struct does not override the new/delete operators. Otherwise, class\struct must implement `operator new(size_t nSize, LPCSTR lpszFileName, int nLine);` and `operator delete(void *p, LPCSTR lpszFileName, int nLine);` Best solution is not to use DEBUG_NEW with DX.

Comment: @23W yes the question is rather old. I worked around by undefining and redefining the debug new definition around the critical place. It's messy but it works, might post it as an answer.